# Can Figma design be exported to Android studio project?

Tags: android-studio, figma

I created an Android application in Android studio and I want to pay a UI/UX designer to redesign it. I did a small research and discovered that most of designers use Figma for making design. My question is: can their design in Figma be exported to my Android studio project (which is implemented in Java and XML)? If the answer is yes, how difficult would integration be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have a look at [this.](https://www.dhiwise.com/post/guide-to-convert-figma-to-android-code) It's not easy but it does the job.

Comment: Dhiwise is easy I have experience in using it

Comment: @blackHawk, The DhiWise does not export the codes in Java. It only exports the code into Kotlin which is a bugger in this scenario!

Answer (score 1):

You can export XML from Figma: click on the screen, go to "Inspect" and change to Android:

[image]

**Be careful though (not the original question but I want to give some unsollicited advice here):** I'm no Figma expert so maybe I'm missing something here, but I personally never do this and would strongly recommend against it, since you get a View object and not a Layout (like ConstraintLayout or LinearLayout or whatever preference you have for that particular screen). Prsonally I'd recommend getting familiar with XML - gives you much more flexibility with designing apps just the way you want to. Also, watch out very carefully for hardcoded values: in my screenshot example you see `android:layout-width:` hardcoded at 375dp (since that's the width of the Figma screen probably), but you'd ofcourse want to set that to `match_parent` or `wrap_content` based on your needs. Generally I'd say you're spending more time fixing screens that you import like this then when you'd simply start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Google's Relay for Figma.
(https://relay.material.io/)

Instead of XML, use Jetpack Compose for the UI.
(https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose)

Your code in Java can be written in Kotlin. (https://developer.android.com/kotlin)

Android Studio will help converting from Java to Kotlin.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can explore Figma plugin that does this job, search design to android or design to code or figma to android on google search as well